# Incorrectly flagged as duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

The question [Get Wifi Interface name on Android [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980826/get-wifi-interface-name-on-android) is flagged as a duplicate of [How to get the wifi network interface name in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507628/how-to-get-the-wifi-network-interface-name-in-java) and they do not appear to be duplicates at all.

The first question is specifically aimed at the *Android* platform.  In fact, [Get Wifi Interface name on Android [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980826/get-wifi-interface-name-on-android) mentions the word *Android* in the title, it is tagged as *android*, and *android-networking*.  The example given in the question is specifically using the Android API.

Mean while, the [How to get the wifi network interface name in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507628/how-to-get-the-wifi-network-interface-name-in-java) question makes no mention of *Android* in the question, or tags at all.  In fact, The only mention of Android is people asking what the target platform is.

The original author of [How to get the wifi network interface name in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507628/how-to-get-the-wifi-network-interface-name-in-java) commented to a question:

> are you developing on android? – dogbane Dec 22 '10 at 11:35
>
> Yes.But I wish if there is anyway to find interface typr from native java Apis – dheeps Dec 22 '10 at 11:58

Clearly they are looking for a *Java* only answer, and not Android specific.

Comment: you can't retract suggested edits, and even if you could, you couldn't do it after it was rejected.

Comment: Was already rejected, rightfully so.  :-)  Thank you!

Comment: Let's remove the retract edit part of this question.  It will distract from your main point (you shouldn't be asking 2 things in the same question anyway).

Comment: I removed the edit question.